# aws - terraform Gateway load balancer target

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I declared my load balancer with my target group.

```
resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  load_balancer_type = "gateway"
  name               = "gwlb-test"

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.Security-Data-1A-subnet.id
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "test" {
  name     = "gwlb-test"
  port     = 6081
  protocol = "GENEVE"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.subnet_vpc_secu.id
  target_type = "instance"


  health_check {
    port     = 80
    protocol = "HTTP"
   
  }
}
```

but I can't find the code to add my two servers through target group.

[image]

I just want to add my instance on target group.

Thank a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [aws_lb_target_group_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment) resource.